# How to convert Float to Number in gee

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to calculate percentile 95th divide to percentile 5th but I have not been able to find how to do this.

```
var start = "2022-01-01"
var end = "2022-12-30"

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
                  .filterDate(start, end)
                  .mean()
                  .clip(table);
var ndvi = dataset.select('NDVI')
.divide(10000);


var veg = ndvi.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([95]), table, 800)
print(veg,'vegetation')

var soil = ndvi.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([5]), table, 800)
print(soil)

print('veg / soil', ee.Number(veg).divide(ee.Number(soil)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of [ee.Image.reduceRegion](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregion) is a dictionary, even if your input image only has one band (in your example `NDVI`). To get the value from the dictionary, use `.get`:

```js
var veg = ndvi.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([95]), table, 800).get("NDVI")
var soil = ndvi.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([5]), table, 800).get("NDVI")
```

Now this should work:

```js
print('veg / soil', ee.Number(veg).divide(ee.Number(soil)));
```

which prints*

```
veg / soil
1.2932496005680811
```

*for the arbitrary region defined here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/65bfdc1fef1b82db6ee410585d111a2f

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your console, you'll notice that `veg` and `soil` are dictionaries (objects), not numbers. That's what `reduceRegion()` returns. All you have to do to extract the actual numbers is to call `getNumber()`.

```
print('veg / soil', veg.getNumber('NDVI').divide(soil.getNumber('NDVI')))
```

Doing two separate `reduceRegion()` calls is quite inefficient though. You can combine them in a single call. You can also get a bit more readable calculations by using expressions (at least when they start to get more complex). Here's how that would look:

```
var percentiles = ndvi
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([5, 95]), 
    geometry: table, 
    scale: 800
  })
print('percentiles', percentiles)

var ratio = ee.Number.expression('NDVI_p95 / NDVI_p5', percentiles)
print('veg / soil', ratio)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c5ef4a2c457d783f61c14d49ea5b0558